# In gdb can structure print be limited?

Tags: printing, stl, gdb

When I print a class in gdb, if my class contains STL members then much useless output is generated, making it hard to see the useful stuff.  Something like this would be better:

```
(gdb) p foo
$2 = {
  count = 0,
  name = <std::string> ...,
  other = 0x4f06f58
}
```

Is this possible in vanilla gdb?

Comment: You can print the individual elements you are interested in.  Ie. `foo.count`

Comment: True, but in this case I want to see what members exist.  Yeah, I know, use a real editor that instantly shows me the definition.

Answer (score 0):

This should not be a problem if your gdb is configured to use [pretty-printers in Python](http://sourceware.org/gdb/wiki/STLSupport). With properly configured pretty-printers the class with STL members should look like this:

```
(gdb) p foo
$2 = {
  count = 0,
  name = "some string",
  other = 0x4f06f58
}
```

Note, that some distributions have already configured pretty-printers.